# 0 rows Deleted/Updated/Inserted require COMMIT in ORACLE?

Tags: database, oracle, locking, commit

In an Oracle database, I just ran a query and I get

> 0 rows deleted.

Does a "0 row" DML operation lock a table in ORACLE and do I need to `COMMIT` if yes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, and yes. Oracle locks rows that are modified etc. - so that won't happen if no rows are affected; but Oracle also creates a subexclusive *table* lock regardless of any rows that may or may not be modified, and it releases such locks only on `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` or equivalent. (Of course, in this case you can also `ROLLBACK` - same effect since no rows are affected).

Demonstrated easily in the following session:

```
SQL> create table xx as
  2  select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 5;

Table created.

SQL> select * from xx;

       LVL
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5

SQL> select a.object_name, b.locked_mode
  2  from   user_objects a join v$locked_object b
  3  on a.object_id = b.object_id;

no rows selected

SQL> delete from xx where lvl = 10;

0 rows deleted.

SQL> select a.object_name, b.locked_mode
  2  from   user_objects a join v$locked_object b
  3  on a.object_id = b.object_id;


OBJECT_NAME     LOCKED_MODE
--------------- -----------
XX                        3

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select a.object_name, b.locked_mode
  2  from   user_objects a join v$locked_object b
  3  on a.object_id = b.object_id;

no rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats acually surprising since no data has changed.